# USB port not working on new case

Tags: usb

I recently built a new computer, and everything is working perfectly fine, except for the top USB port on the case.

The case used is a [Thor V2](http://www.rosewill.com/products/1798/productDetail.htm), and the motherboard is an [Asus P8Z68-V PRO/GEN3](http://www.asus.de/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_1155/P8Z68V_PROGEN3/).

The two cables that connect the front USB ports to the motherboard come together at one header, which is plugged into the USB socket on the motherboard.
The bottom port works fine, but the top does not.

I have tried it in the other sockets on the motherboard, with no change. When I plug anything into the top one, the led will come on for a second or so, as though it will work, but it will go off, and windows will report device driver not installed, device not working.

What could be the source of this problem? The cable looks fine, and so does the header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There still might be a defect in the header or the cable you didn't notice yet. I suggest you bring it back to the shop and get a new one.

Comment: I wish, the 30 day newegg warranty is up. Anything else I can do?

Comment: Try to find replacement parts I'm affraid :/